# WebStorm and PHPStorm debug php and js at same time

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, phpstorm, webstorm

Imagine I have a test.html file which contains a jQuery line which calls a test.php file like in the example below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Debug test</title>
        <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready( function()
            {
                jQuery('#testdiv').load('test.php' );
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="testdiv">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now imagine the php file test.php returns a result like in the example below:

```
<?php
test();

function test()
{
    echo "Ok called me!";
}
?>
```

The two files of course run under a server like Apache.

What I'd like to accomplish would be something like in NetBeans Java EE debug: put a debug breakpoint in test.php fun() function and one in the jquery call inside test.html, then call localhost/test.html and see the first breakpoint inside jquery call being hit and then the second breakpoint inside test.php being hit.

How can I obtain (if possible) this using jetBrains Intellidea WebStorm and PHPStorm?
Thank you

Comment: FYI: WebStorm does NOT support PHP debugging.

Comment: I mentioned Intellidea WebStorm and PHPStorm as a combination to make this possible, not one or the other alone. Still wondering whether it is somehow possible to debug php and js together anyway.

Comment: Yes, you can -- in PhpStorm (no need for two IDEs running at the same time). PHP Debugger (Xdebug) should be configured to start debugging **automatically** + Zero-Configuration approach should be used (phone handle icon on main toolbar) -- http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm

Comment: **The idea is:** 1) activate PHP debugger in PhpStorm (phone handle icon); 2) Launch JavaScript debug to debug your JS code. When request will be made to a PHP file, xdebug will contact PhpStorm to debug PHP code. When PHP debug portion will be finished, you should be able to continue debugging your JS code. **P.S.** This assumes that you already configured IDE and able to debug PHP and JS **separately**.

Comment: I am able to debug test.html and test.php separately, XDEBUG is correctly activated however when I open localhost/test.html no incoming debug call is received. From the guide http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm I cannot understand the part "Set initial path mappings", can you tell me where to find that menu?

Comment: 1) Zero configuration (the link I gave you) is to debug **PHP code**. For JavaScript you need to debug it in normal way. 2) If Zero-config does not work for **PHP** page, then quite likely you did not configured xdebug properly (or your existing config (in PhpStorm) for PHP is "not compatible" -- don't know better words for this). Better create new empty project and try PHP debug there. When all done -- switch back to real project (apply similar settings). You can try deleting your PHP-debug related settings (in particular: `Settings | PHP | Servers`).

Comment: Ok got it now, I can debug php file opening localhost/test.html. However there's one missing point, the jquery inside test.html cannot be debugged at the same time, but need to debug it separately inside PHPStorm. How to do it together? otherwise I'm debugging js and php separately and that's not exactly what I was looking for in my question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36043/discussion-between-dendini-and-lazyone)

Comment: I have tried debugging **[these two -- check attachments](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5478686#5478686)** ajax projects (JS + PHP) as well as **[this one](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/09/html5-file-upload-jquery-php/)** -- I can debug both JS and PHP (starting with JS debug; when ajax request is sent, PHP debug kicks in; when PHP is done -- back to JS debug). You must be doing something wrong/differently if it does not work for you (please check the 4th comment again)

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**:

As LazyOne suggested I should use "zero configuration" option inside PhpStorm, complete instructions at [jetbrains/...](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm)

Below is a description of the steps:

1. Install Xdebug (sudo apt-get install php5-xdebug)
2. Add inside /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini the lines:

   > [Xdebug]
   >   zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/xdebug.so
   >       xdebug.remote_enable=1
   >       xdebug.remote_host=localhost
   >       xdebug.remote_port=9000
3. restart apache: "service apache2 restart"
4. check Xdebug is enabled "php --version" should show "with xDebug vx.x"
5. Toggle the “Listen debugger connections” button.[image: listen debug connections], this will listen for incoming connections to the test.php script
6. Set a breakpoint in the test.php source code
7. Activate the xdebug debugger, to do this we need to set a special GET/POST or COOKIE parameter. You can do it manually, but it is much more convenient to use a special online tool [bookmerklets generator](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/)

   [image]
8. Open localhost/test.php and you will see a request to start debugging at line of test.php.

Comment: You may want to use this also, dude :)
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc